# Toggle recyclerview item background w/databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Problem: toggling value "isSelected" is not changing item background ie

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="isSelected"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/rv_item_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background='@{isSelected ? @drawable/border1 : null}'
        >
```

In my recyclerview, each dataclass has a property "isSelected" ie

```
data class BillNotif(val name: String){
var isSelected: Boolean = false
}
```

I have a function in my adapter I call from my fragment to toggle this value

```
fun toggleSelected(position: Int){
        Log.d("items?", "$position,${list[position]},${list[position].isSelected }")
        list[position].isSelected = !list[position].isSelected
        Log.d("items?", "$position,${list[position]},${list[position].isSelected }")
    }
```

^this function appears to be working, However the background doesnt change.  Here is my viewHolder where I set the binding value

```
inner class ViewHolder(val binding: EditBillnotifRvItemBinding, val parent: ViewGroup): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

        fun bind(item: BillNotif, position: Int) {
            Log.d("ITEM??", "$item")
            binding.name.text = item.name
            binding.isSelected = item.isSelected
            val drawableBorder = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(parent.context, R.drawable.border1)
            binding.rvItemContainer.setOnClickListener {
                item.isSelected = !item.isSelected
                clickListener(item, position)
                if (item.isSelected == true) binding.rvItemContainer.background = drawableBorder else binding.rvItemContainer.background = null
            }
        }
    }
```

it appears that my toggle function is not updating "binding.isSelected"

In my Fragment here is how I am calling the toggle function,"adapter.toggleSelected"

```
       adapter = BillNotifsSetListAdapter {item, position ->
            Log.d("isArgsworking?", "$item")
            if(isNotifSelected == null){
                isNotifSelected = true
                selectedNotif = item
                selectedPosition = position
            }else{
                if(isNotifSelected == true){
                    Log.d("HIT1","HIT1")
                    if (selectedNotif != item){
                        Log.d("HIT2","HIT2")
                        selectedPosition?.let { adapter.toggleSelected(it) }
                    }
            }
        }
```

The ultimate goal here is to only have the background change for a single item that is selected at a time.

Comment: I update the code adding "adapter.notifyItemChanged(position)"  after my function call "selectedPosition?.let { adapter.toggleSelected(it) }"

The root cause appears to be, how do I invoke the "bind" function on the item that changed the "isSelected" value, or how can each item observe/react to the value being toggled to change the databinding value.

Comment: Ok, I figured this out, I was passing the incorrect value to adapter.notifyItemChanged(position), but this is working:)